# Where should I add CakeLog::config

Tags: cakephp

I am using 1.3. I read about cake logging activites in  book.cakephp
But in which file should i add CakeLog::config() for setting up logging details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure log adapters in your applications **bootstrap.php** file. A sample configuration would look like:

```
CakeLog::config('my_log', array('engine' => 'FileLog'));
```